# What's the reason to add a simple static <style> tag via document.write()?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just looked at the page source of a [random app page](http://apptivate.ms/apps/28/metrose) on apptivate.ms and noticed this JavaScript in the `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("<style type=\"text/css\">.app-description { max-height: 600px }</style>");
</script>
```

It is obviously totally static on the client side so I wonder what the use-case there is. Since they Stack Exchange developers (who are behind apptivate.ms) are pretty smart I'm *sure* there is some reason for it, but I can't figure out which. I guess it's related to delaying the rule from becoming active until the whole document is loaded but I'd expect the rule to be applied as soon as the browser "sees" the new tag...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because part of the content of the `.app-description` element is hidden, and can be shown by clicking a "Show more" button.

If JavaScript is disabled, the button won't work, so if the style in question was directly in the stylesheet, you could never see the rest of the content. By adding that style in the `<head>`, with JavaScript, it ensures that users with JS enabled will not see all the content at once, but will instead get the "enhanced" experience, and those *without* JS enabled will still be able to use the site.

Here's a screenshot when JS is enabled. The "show more" button uses JavaScript to expand the element to full height:

[image]

This is a nice approach to progressive enhancement - by using `document.write` to insert the new `style` element inside the `head` you avoid any possible flash of unstyled content (in this case, the developers could have waited until DOM ready and then used JavaScript to add the `maxHeight` property dynamically, but that would have resulted in users seeing the full height briefly before the JavaScript executed on DOM ready).

Comment: a.k.a. progressive enhancement. Just realized there is a ton of stuff i need to correct in my app.. Tks..

Comment: @techfoobar I wouldn't use this method if that is what you are planning by "ton of stuff that needs correcting". Far better and easier is to apply a `class="js"` to your body tag for javascript-enabled users, and then target your css accordingly.

Comment: Of course. I'm not gonna add script tags everywhere. But i remembered the tons of users i've been ignoring till now because of the lack of this realization.

Comment: I'd say showing it by default and hiding it via a CSS within `<noscript>` tags would be cleaner. But I guess there was some reason to do it that way (or maybe the developer just wrote it before drinking his first coffee? :p)

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Yeah I agree, a `noscript` element in the `head` would be nicer than a `document.write`. I can't think of any special reason it would have to be done the way it is... each to their own I guess.

Comment: Let's all laugh at the weirdo who uses `document.write()` on a programming competition website.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - You've got it the wrong way round. The idea is to show everything on no JS, so you'd have to hide by default and show on `<noscript>`. But that doesn't work, because content filters might remove the JS, while JS remains on in the browser. So the content of `<noscript>` has no effect, and the text remains hidden to those users behind the content filter.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as "progressive" enhancement. Basically, the notion is simple; don't assume that everyone will have JavaScript enabled, even if 98% of them will...but if they do, let's do some nice things with it.

The idea is to have your **DOM** (HTML) in place and working without the explicit **NEED** to have JS enabled to use it.

Then, if the JS loads (which it would have to in this case to add that style) you can target an element with a specific class name. In this case, it is `.app-description`. If you don't have JS on, the item in question remains unaffected.

Hope that makes some sense :)

**EDIT**: Now, you could still load a JS file that does some CSS things, but the reason it is placed IN the script tag itself on the page, is because you can then avoid the HTTP request all-together if it isn't needed.

Comment: Ah heh, good point.  I obviously knew about PE but didn't really consider it in this case. However, I'd rather use `<noscript>` instead to override the original CSS rule....